# How to determine what cell has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs3

I am new to JavaScript and I am having to use ExtJS 3.4.  I have created a simple tree with 3 columns.  I would like to know either what cell was selected, or even, just what row and column were selected.

I am just using the example that Sencha uses at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html :

```
  var tree = new Ext.ux.tree.TreeGrid({
    title: 'Core Team Projects',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    enableDD: true,

    columns:[{
        header: 'Task',
        dataIndex: 'task',
        width: 230
    },{
        header: 'Duration',
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'duration',
        align: 'center',
        sortType: 'asFloat',
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{duration:this.formatHours}', {
            formatHours: function(v) {
                if(v < 1) {
                    return Math.round(v * 60) + ' mins';
                } else if (Math.floor(v) !== v) {
                    var min = v - Math.floor(v);
                    return Math.floor(v) + 'h ' + Math.round(min * 60) + 'm';
                } else {
                    return v + ' hour' + (v === 1 ? '' : 's');
                }
            }
        })
    },{
        header: 'Assigned To',
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'user'
    }],

    dataUrl: 'treegrid-data.json'
});
```

Is it possible to do this in ExtJS 3.4?  I can get the node but I do not see where it is telling me what cell or column or row was selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to attach listeners e.g.

```
 listeners: {
                afterRender: function(p) {
                    p.body.on('click', function() { // Function tapping clicks on Panel
                    alert(p.getTargetEl().dom.innerHTML);

                                            });
                    });

             }
```

Comment: pleasure, glad that I could help